# Bars on polar bar plots are cut off when rlim is set

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making some bar plots using a polar projection.  The data are all large numbers far from the origin and thus I'm using the ax.set_rlim to make them easier to distinguish.  However, when I set the rlim, some of the bars are cut off around the origin.  This is not an issue when I do not set the rlim, but I can't present my data like this.  Why is this happening and is there a way I can fix it?

Here is an example of the issue:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

Sectors = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,np.pi/4)
Data = np.array([100,99,100,101,100.5,100.25,99.25,99.75])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.bar(Sectors,Data)
ax.set_rlim(98,102)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note, this does not happen if I don't apply the rlim.  eg:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

Sectors = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,np.pi/4)
Data = np.array([100,99,100,101,100.5,100.25,99.25,99.75])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.bar(Sectors,Data)
#ax.set_rlim(98,102)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange effect indeed.

But there seems to be a workaround using the `bottom` keyword to `bar`. The trick is to set the `bottom` to the inner `rlim` (in this case 98) and specify the data relative to the bottom value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Sectors = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,np.pi/4)
Data = np.array([100,99,100,101,100.5,100.25,99.25,99.75])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.bar(Sectors,Data-98, bottom=98) 
ax.set_rlim(98,102)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a silly round-off error in matplotlib. I bumped up your numbers by a factor 10 and all but one wedge showed correctly. Setting the rlim() to a larger range also shows some improvement. If you need to put this in a presentation, cover up the middle with a drawn in circle.

All bandaids I am afraid....

Comment: If i can't fix it in python I think i'll output as .svg and fix it manually in inkscape.